# AWS Cloudformation: How do I check if a bucket exists from within the Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

In my CloudFormation template, I'm trying to create an S3 Bucket only if S3 doesn't already have a bucket that includes a certain keyword in it's name. For example, if my keyword is 'picture', I only want this S3 bucket to be created if no bucket in S3 contains the word 'picture' in its name.

```
    "Resources": {
        "myBucket": {
            "Condition" : "<NO_S3_BUCKET_WITH_'picture'_IN_ITS_NAME_IN_THIS_ACCOUNT>",
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                <SOME_PROPERTIES>
            }
        },
        <OTHER_RESOURCES>
    }
```

Is this possible? if so, can it be done with other AWS resources (CloudFront Distribution etc.)?

Comment: How did it go? Is is still unclear what you can't do what you want and what you should do?

Comment: I ended up taking another approach as developing a custom resource isn't worth it in this case. But I now understand that I can't do that logic in plain CloudFormation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not with plain CloudFormation. You would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to do this.